# Applescript Editor's compiler erratic behaviour

Tags: snow-leopard, applescript

I've just come across some bizarre behaviour in the Applescript Editor (Snow Leopard - 10.6.8) that I was wondering if anyone knows how to get around it.

Basically, one second a statement will compile and run ok, but as soon as I change the code and revert to the original text it fails to compile again.

For example, the following screenshot shows the code compiled and run ok with the results shown at the bottom.

[image: Code is OK]

Now, I copied the line to a new window and the code no longer compiles! The leading spacing matters not, I did it so it is visible. The quotes it complains about are fine. Re-entering them makes no difference. Other times is replaced the test `application process` with `<<class pcap>>`.

[image: Code is NOK!]

It gets worse. After googling to figure out what is going on, I saw someone suggest using brackets. I did and it worked! I made some change it broke again!

Anyone know what is going on?

EDIT:
Applescript Editor ver: 2.3
Applescript ver: 2.1.2

Please not bother suggesting I upgrade the OS. My old 2008 macbook is slow enough as it is. :(